# Accidentally lost my /etc/profile

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script tied to `/etc/profile` but instead of appending, I accidentally wrote over it, losing all its contents. How can I restore the file?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the template of `/etc/profile` in `/usr/share/base-files/profile`
If you want to restart with a new one, you can easily copy it :

```
sudo cp /usr/share/base-files/profile /etc/profile
```

Comment: The files in `/etc/skel` are copied to the home directories of new users. The file `/etc/profile` is a system-wide configuration file and somewhat different.

Comment: @mook765 They updated the answer with a file that does match the default `/etc/profile`.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Thanks, removed downvote, edited and upvoted...